# Group By Linq ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I currently display a list of errors from a database. As you can see from the image below, there are a number of errors that share the same Application Name.[image]

I am wanting to group all the errors with the same name together and just show the one error with that application name instead of all of them.

I have looked at other questions on here related to what I am doing but none of them have given me the answer I require.

This is my current code.

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                     select s;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            applications = applications.Where(s => s.Application.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            default:
                applications = applications.OrderBy(x => x.Application).ThenByDescending(s => s.TimeUtc);
                break;
        }


        int pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

### View

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DataIntelligence.Models.ElmahError>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Application Error Dashboard";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Application Error Dashboard</h2>
</div> 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Application", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by Application: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Application
        </th>
        <th>
            Host
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
           Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Message
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id=item.ErrorId})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application) </a>      
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Host)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)

        </td>
        <td >
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeUtc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        </td>


    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of     @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

How would I go about changing this code in order to achieve what I am wanting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace:

```
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                 select s;
```

With:

```
var applications = db.ElmahErrors
  .GroupBy(s => s.Application)
  .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
```

Then the query will only deal with one element for each application.

You might also wish to do this grouping at a later state, if there were elements in `ElmahErrors` you wanted to filter out, on some other criteria, to make sure you didn't happen to filter out the distinct item chosen when there was another item with the same `Application` that wouldn't have been filtered.

Comment: Note on an attempted edit: It's pointless to replace `grp.First()` with `grp.FirstOrDefault()`; `grp` cannot be empty by definition. Obtaining the `First()` is a better expression of what the code is intended to do, than obtaining the `FirstOrDefault()` when there's no meaningful  `or default` in the context.

Comment: But when you just use `First()` you get this error `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.` When you use `FirstOrDefault()` then it works, hence the suggested edit.

Comment: Hmm. That is most curious. You're using an up to date version of EF?

Comment: Well, that's a nuisance. You've a working answer, which is great, but it's still a nuisance that EF doesn't support `First()` directly here.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at 'MoreLinq', perhaps their DistinctBy provides the answer you need. It is available in NuGet.
[MoreLINQ's DistinctBy for C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/)

Should work something like this:

```
List<ElmahErrors> distinctByError = db.ElmahErrors.DistinctBy(x => x.Message).ToList();
```

Comment: Does MoreLINQ handle `IQueryable<T>` directly now? It certainly used to just do everything in memory, which would be very expensive here.

Comment: No, MoreLINQ still uses IEnumerable<T>. OP could make his selection smaller, but it would still use a lot more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
 group c by new
    {
        s.Application,
        s.Host,
        s.Type, 
        s.Date,
        s.Message
    } into gcs
    select new ElmahErrors()
    {
        gcs.key.Application,
        gcs.key.Host,
        gcs.key.Type, 
        gcs.key.Date,
        gcs.key.Message
    };
```

Comment: Becouse it groups also by date. Remove grouping by date

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from a in applications
              group a by a.Application into g
              select new { Application = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), LastDate = g.Max(d=>d.Date) };
```

Or if you want to group by more coulms:

```
 var results = from a in applications
                  group a by new {a.Application, a.Message} into g
                  select new { Application = g.Key.Application, Message = g.Key.Message, Count = g.Count(), LastDate = g.Max(d=>d.Date) };
```